# Java addition, while loop and joptionpane

Tags: java, while-loop, joptionpane

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction it would be amazing.
I'm trying to write a program that prompts a user to enter 5 integer values and then output the product of the values entered but just can't figure it out.

I can't figure out how exactly to multiply each input by the user. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. This is what I've got so far.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ex2Pa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0;
        while(count <5){

            String Msg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
            int Num1 = Integer.parseInt(Msg);


            System.out.print(Num1);
            count++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `int product = 1;` ... in the loop `product *= Num1;`.

Comment: @KevinEsche Why don't you post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;
    int result = 1;
    while (count < 5) {

        String Msg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
        int Num1 = Integer.parseInt(Msg);


        System.out.print(Num1);
        result *= Num1;
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println("The result is " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    int count = 0;
    int result =1; 
    while(count <5){

                String Msg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
                int Num = Integer.parseInt(Msg);


                System.out.print(Num);
                result = result*Num;
                count++;
            } 
   System.out.println("Result--->"+result);
```

In last,you can print `result` to show final result.

Comment: Thanks all much appreciated